NEXTJS redirect issue
"use server";
import { customFetch } from "./customFetch";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { BadRequestError } from "./ErrorHandler";
import uploadFileToS3 from "./uploadFileToS3";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export const registerNewUser = async (prevState: any, formData: FormData) => {
  const image = formData.get("image") as File;
  if (!image) return;
  if (!["image/jpeg", "image/png"].includes(image.type.toLowerCase())) {
    throw new BadRequestError("Image type should be JPEG or PNG Only.");
  }
  if (image.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
    throw new BadRequestError("Image size should not exceed 5MB.");
  }
  const buffer = Buffer.from(await image.arrayBuffer());
  const uploadedImage = await uploadFileToS3(buffer, image.name, image.type);
  const user = {
    firstName: formData.get("firstName") as string,
    lastName: formData.get("lastName") as string,
    password: formData.get("password") as string,
    confirmPassword: formData.get("confirmPassword") as string,
    email: formData.get("email") as string,
    image: uploadedImage,
  };
  try {
    const { data } = await customFetch.post("/api/auth/sign-up", user);
    revalidatePath("/");
    // redirect("/");
    return data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.response.data.error);
    return { message: error.response.data.error };
  }
};

import { connectDB } from "../../../../lib/mongoose";
import { User, userValidation, loginValidation } from "../../../../models/User";
import { BadRequestError } from "../../../../lib/ErrorHandler";
import asyncHandler from "../../../../lib/asyncHandler";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";


export const POST = asyncHandler(async (req: NextRequest) => {
  await connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
  const data = await req.json();
  const { error, value } = userValidation.validate(data);
  if (error) throw new BadRequestError(error.details[0].message);
  const isEmailExist = await User.findOne({ email: value.email });
  if (isEmailExist) {
    throw new BadRequestError("email is already exist");
  }

  const user = new User(value);
  await user.save();
  // redirect('/');
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      message: `Success Signing Up!`,
      success: true,
      user,
    },
    { status: 201 }
  );
});

I think this is one of the most easy solutions out there, but yet im stuck on it for a long time hehe.
I want to be able to redirect to the home page after signin up, I cant figure out how can i redirect to the home page and return data or nextreponse, cause when i redirect, the return statement is not accessible.
I shared 2 files cause im not sure even where to write the redirect logic.
thanks in advance.
